# Using or operator multiple times

Tags: java

Is it possible to  use 'or' operator multiple times without getting an error in java

```
  if(var=="20"|"22"|"24"....))
```

Answer (score 4):

`|` is bitwise  [OR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). You need to use `||`

Syntax should be something like below for your requirement

```
if(var.equals("20")|| var.equals("22")|| var.equals("24"))
```

Comment: I want to use variable only one time. Is it possible like that?

Comment: No, it is not possible with API calls.

Comment: Well, if you wanted something like that, you could write `String[] arr = {"20", "22", "24"}; for (String s: arr) { if (var.equals(s)) { yourCodeHere(); } }`, but a [mathematical operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28mathematics%29) doesn't work like our English where we make a bunch of things implicit.

Comment: or simple add all your values to list and do contains().

Comment: @Nambari Oh yeah, it's been 2 years now; I forgot about `contains`.

Comment: @Bohemian OP wants logical OR. For instance, if OP wasn't using strings but rather numbers, `20|22|24` would be disastrous.

Comment: @Bohemian: Though your point is valid, I am not saying | is not OR operator. I have explicitly pointed OP to operators tutorial also there, and logical OR is different from bit-wise OR and 2rs2ts explained why || is needed here.

Comment: @2rs2ts the opening sentence is wrong. `|` is both bitwuse or *and* the non-short circuiting logical OR operator

Comment: `||` is NOT required here! I could code it with `|` and it would work

Answer (score 1):

Lots of problems here.

First, you can't compare strings using `==`, which tests if the 2 operands are the *same* object. Use `equals()`:

```
if (var.equals("21"))
```

Next, you can't group up operands like that, you must use separate calls to `equals()`, but instead of that you can also do this:

```
if (Arrays.asList("20", "22", "24", ....).contains(var))
```

Comment: This is less efficient than the switch statement. That can use the hashCode to (usually) not-compare many Strings. I agree that this is easier to maintain, so probably a better choice (but moving the Arrays.asList out of the loop would be preferred if this is in a loop).

Comment: @gabor *... 97% of the time, premature [optimization](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization) is the root of all evil* - [Donald Knuth](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: I agree and aware of this. I was just pointing out that similar things were the reason of introducing the switch with Strings statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the [switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) (works with strings too, since Java 7).
Using or is not what you want in my opinion.
Example:

```
switch (var) {
    case "20"://document fall-through to prevent future changes
    case "22"://no break here either
    case "24":
        //do what you want.
    break;
}
```